# Mysql : Insert null timestamp into NOT NULL column

Tags: mysql

Mysql version is 5.1.73,there can be only one `timestamp` column with `current_timestamp` in `deafault` or `on update` clause,so I tried to create table:

```
create table `temp`( 
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
  `created_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_updated_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And after I executed this sql:

```
insert into `temp`(id,created_date, last_updated_date) values(1,null, null);
```

I got this document:

```
1   2017-02-10 18:17:16 2017-02-10 18:18:13
```

Here is my question:

- I set `created_date` NOT NULL,why did the insert sql work well?Should it return `Error: Column 'xx' cannot be null`？
- Why did `created_date` column get a value and it is not the **default value**?

Thanks.

Comment: NULL !=0; NULL <> 0; NULL=??????????? Your default is a value NULL has no value.

Answer (score 1):

That's how the `MySql`'s `TIMESTAMP` work, if you want to get an error on `NULL` the way to go is to use `DATETIME` instead.

So if you create the following table

```
create table `temp`( 
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_updated_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And then execute the below query you'll get the error.

```
insert into `temp`(id,created_date, last_updated_date) values(1,null, null);
```

Now you'll start getting this error `#1048 - Column 'created_date' cannot be null`.